# Why can't jQuery dataTables parse my JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to populate a [dataTable](http://datatables.net/index) as follows:

```
$("#my-datatable").dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource" : "/someURLOnMyServer",
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "fnServerParams" : function(serverParams) {
        serverParams.push(
            {
                "name" : "widget",
                "value" : token
            }
        );
    }
});
```

And the HTML table it is populating:

```
<table id="my-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Fizz</th>
            <th>Buzz</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

According to Firebug, the JSON coming back from the server is:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "attributeType":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"test1",
         "tag":"test-type",
         "is-dog":false
      },
      "attributeValue":{
         "id":null,
         "name":"blah",
         "tag":"BLAH"
      },
      "buzz":1,
      "fizz":"53abc"
   }
]
```

But Firebug is throwing the following JavaScript error in its console:

```
TypeError: aData is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) --> jquery.dataTables.js (line 2541)
```

Can anyone spot what's going wrong? Either I'm not setting up my `dataTable` object correctly, or the JSON coming back doesn't match the "schema" of the HTML table it is trying to populate. Either way, I'm lost. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know much about jQuery dataTables, but I'd have to wonder if the fact that the JSON that is being returned is as an array might be the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Datatables requires a certain format for results. If you are not using that format, you have to declare everything.

```
$('#my-datatable').dataTable( {

    "sAjaxSource": "/url/here",


    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "widget", "value": "token" } );

            request = $.ajax({
              "dataType": 'json', 
              "type": "GET", 
              "url": sSource, 
              "data": aoData, 
              "success": fnCallback
            });
      },


      "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "id"},
            { "mDataProp": "fizz"},
            { "mDataProp": "name"},
            { "mDataProp": "tag"},
            { "mDataProp": "tag"},
            { "mDataProp": "attributeValue.name"},
            { "mDataProp": "attributeValue.tag"},
        ],

    });
```

This is the format: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: Thanks again @Aktee (+1) - but this is confusing me even more! What are `sSource`, `aoData`, `fnCallback`, `aoData` and `mDataProp`, **and where do they come from** (where are they declared)? I'm *guessing* that your code snippet above is just an abstract example of what my code will have to look like, however, I don't have enough information to be able to take your example and fit it to my problem. Same goes for the link you sent me, and all the dataTables documentation. There's decent demos and snippets, but no *working*, real-world examples of it in action.

Comment: Its hard without examples, here's one with exactly your data. http://maktouch.net/pnongrata/

Comment: @pnongrata, did u have a chance to check my hosted example?

Comment: @pnongrata Is it okay or not?

Comment: Sorry @Aktee I have been out of town since last week. I am checking now - thanks for the help so far and the follow-up

Comment: @Aktee the link `http://maktouch.net/pnongrata/` is broken, could you add an explanation about the way to use it in the `php` file? I printed `$_GET`, `$_POST` and also `$router` (*codeigniter*). And none of these bring me the data

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, why do they hide this page so well? datatables.net

Answer (score 1):

Try to enclose your JSON object with `aaData` like:

```
{"aaData" : 

[{"id":1,"attributeType":{"id":1,"name":"test1","tag":"test-type","is-dog":false},"attributeValue":{"id":null,"name":"blah","tag":"BLAH"},"buzz":1,"fizz":"53abc"}]

}
```