# Datatables TypeError: aData is undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I want to populate datatables with database values in a table. Below is my code listing, everything seems to be ok but an error is returned "TypeError: aData is undefined" so datatables is not created

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listax').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax_live/getUsers",
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null //put as many null values as your columns
        ]
    });
});
</script>

<table id="listax"></table>
```

Server side

```
 function getUsers(){
     $this->db->select('id,username');
     $query = $this->db->get('user');
     $data = $query->result();
     echo json_encode($data); 
 }
```

This is the data returned by json encode

```
[
    {"id":"6","username":"Lab23"},
    {"id":"11","username":"MaryMM"}
]
```

Comment: Can you try printing the $data before encoding it, I suspect it returns empty results.

Comment: chandresh_cool, it does not return an empty result, i have edited the code to show what is returned

Comment: You do not return right json data to Datatable, check here http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html the output in the php code

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this I have had to define the columns.
Example array being sent back;

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [username] => "Lab23"
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [username] => "MaryMM"
        )
)
```

So if your json encoded array has key values of **id** and **username** the datatables would have the following segment in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listax').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax_live/getUsers",
        "aoColumns":[
            {"mDataProp":"id"},
            {"mDataProp":"username"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: I have edited the code listing to show what json encode returns

Comment: Yea, i have tried the code and it has not worked, the same error

Comment: @user2249879 have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847627/why-cant-jquery-datatables-parse-my-json