# aData is undefined in datatables jquery plug-in?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using `1.9.4 -jquery.dataTables.js`. I get `aData is undefined` error. I have seen several posts that on this issue, I tried everything but none helped.

My `JSON object` that is returned is what datatables expects. it has "aaData" field which is an array of arrays. I am trying out with only one column to fix the bug.

I get a pop-up error-message on the browser

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'search_table'): list index out of rangelist index out of range
```

In the firebug console, I see

```
aData is undefined in 2038 at jquery.dataTable.js

for ( var i=0, iLen=aData.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
{....
```

my json object;

```
{"result": "ok", "iTotalRecords": 5, "aaData": [["6200"], ["6900"], ["7500"], ["5800"], ["4600"]], "sEcho": 0, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 5}
```

my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#search_table').dataTable( {
        //"sDom": 'T<"clear">lrtip',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/search/list",
        //"aData":"aaData"
        //"sAjaxDataProp": "aaData"
        //"aoColumns":[
         //   {"mDataProp":""},
           // {"mDataProp":"username"}
        //]
        //"aaSorting": [ [1,'desc'], [2,'desc'] ],
        // Disable sorting for the Actions column.
        //"aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] } ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="well">
                <table id="search_table">
                    <thead>
                            <th width="10%"><center>Title</center></th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table><br>
</div>
```

Comment: you insert the parameter "result"?? what if you not return this parameter?

Comment: "result" comes from django-datatable-plugin I use. I don't think it matters here

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847627/why-cant-jquery-datatables-parse-my-json

Comment: yes, I did. but their the json returned is in wrong format. Here I have the correct format..

Comment: if you debug datatable.js and look when aData is assigned. Maybe also console.log(aData); before the for loop.

Comment: maybe this can help too http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2783/json-format/p1

Comment: i tried removing "results" from json object. now there is no error but table is not loaded. any idea why?

Comment: and json is correct? if is correct maybe django plugins need the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `"bServerSide": true`, and see if it works. I guess you are not doing any serverside proecessing now